# Strange characters appearing after copy/pasting in forms/emails

Tags: php, mysql

I have users who sometimes paste things into my site's forms after copying something from their Gmail.  The characters look normal when they paste it, but in the database they have extra special characters that appear.

Here is an example of the text with the the special characters.
It originally happened on this page:
http://www.hikingsanfrancisco.com/hiker_community/scheduled_hike_event.php?hike_event_id=91

But it looks like the person who made it has cleaned up the strange characters.

Does anyone know how to stop this from happening in the future?

Thanks,
Alex

I use PHP and MySQL

Comment: Hard to say anything without seeing the actual characters...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd guess that you're getting UTF-8 encoded text but your database is configured for ISO-8859-1 (AKA Latin-1). The page you reference says:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

so it is claiming to be encoded as UTF-8. A form on a UTF-8 page will be sent back to the server in UTF-8. Then you send that UTF-8 data into your database where it is stored as Latin-1 encoded text. If you're not handling the UTF-8 to Latin-1 change yourself then you'll get "funny" characters when you send the data back to a browser. As long as the text only uses standard ASCII characters then everything will be okay as UTF-8 and Latin-1 overlap on the ASCII characters.

The solution is to pick a character encoding and use it everywhere. I'd recommend UTF-8 everywhere. However, if your database is already in Latin-1 then you'll have to go with Latin-1 or change the encoding in the database and re-encode all the data. But, if all the text in your database is simple ASCII then no re-encoding will be needed.

Hard to say what's going without examples but a character encoding mismatch is the usual problem when funny (funny peculiar, not funny ha-ha) characters appear only when text is sent back to the browser.

Comment: Thank you.  Couple of questions: 1) How do I find out which character set my DB is using?  2) If my DB is using a non-UTF-8 char set, what are the negative consequences of encoding my HTML forms in a non-UTF char set?

Comment: Executing `status;` from the MySQL shell will tell you the server, client, DB, and connection character sets. Using Latin-1 in the HTML is fine if you're only targeting the US and English, just make sure your pages tell the browser that they're Latin-1; if you have to deal with anything other than English then you should use UTF-8 front to back to save your sanity. The most important thing is that everything -- HTML you send out, forms that come back, and the database -- works with the same encoding and the sooner the better.

Comment: You might want to do some reading here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset.html

Comment: So last question.  I checked the DM and it is latin1 and on the front end I have UTF-8.  So what should I do with my DB?  Do I need to do something to every table?  What will happen to the latin-1 data in the db if I change the db to UTF-8?  Thank you!

Comment: and can some tables be declared as UTF-8 and some tables as latin1? Or that would just create a total mess? :)

Comment: I've never had to do such a thing while preserving data. Looks like you have to change the default character set for the database and then change the character set on each table: http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,2574,25131 Of course you'll want to have a complete backup of your database and do a few dry runs on a non-production database first.

Comment: I think mixing character sets in one database would lead to a lot of swearing and quite possibly hard drinking at some point. Both of those things might be fine with you but I don't think mixing character sets would be a healthy reason for either.